# Python: JSON Data to Pandas, Nest List Comprehension

Tags: python, pandas, list-comprehension

I'm using YahooFinancials to get the stock price and volume for a list of several companies. I can extract the prices and volume to separate dataframes, but would like to get both price and volume into the same dataframe without having to merge them after the fact. I believe what I need is a nested list comprehension, but I'm not quite sure how to achieve this?

My code as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
import numpy as np
from yahoofinancials import YahooFinancials
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

from datetime import date, timedelta
import warnings

%matplotlib inline
%config InlineBackend.figure_format = 'retina'

plt.style.use('seaborn')

start = date(2007,1,1)
end = date(2020,6,4)
today = date.today()
tomorrow = str(end + timedelta(days=1))

portfolio = ['AMZN', 'GOOGL', 'MSFT']
yahoo_financials = YahooFinancials(portfolio)

data = yahoo_financials.get_historical_price_data(start_date=str(start), end_date=str(today), time_interval='daily')

prices = pd.DataFrame({a: {x['formatted_date']: x['adjclose'] for x in data[a]['prices']} for a in portfolio})

volume = pd.DataFrame({a: {x['formatted_date']: x['volume'] for x in data[a]['prices']} for a in portfolio})
```

Ideally, the output looks something like this:

```
date      AMZNPrice AMZNVolume GOOGLPrice GOOGLVolume MSFTPrice MSFTVolume
6/9/2020    2600.860107 5176000 1452.079956 1681200 189.800003  29783900
6/10/2020   2647.449951 4946000 1464.699951 1588100 196.839996  43872300
6/11/2020   2557.959961 5800100 1401.900024 2357200 186.270004  52854700
6/12/2020   2545.02002  5429600 1412.920044 1832900 187.740005  43345700
6/15/2020   2572.679932 3865100 1420.73999  1523400 188.940002  32712500
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
data = yahoo_financials.get_historical_price_data(start_date=str(start), end_date=str(today), time_interval='daily')

dfs = []
for s in portfolio:
    df = pd.json_normalize(data[s]['prices'])
    df['stock'] = s
    df = df[['stock', 'formatted_date', 'adjclose', 'volume']]
    dfs.append(df)

df = pd.concat(dfs)
df = pd.pivot(df, index='formatted_date', columns='stock', values=['adjclose', 'volume'])
df.columns = ['_'.join(col) for col in df.columns.values]
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
                adjclose_AMZN  adjclose_GOOGL  adjclose_MSFT  volume_AMZN  volume_GOOGL  volume_MSFT
formatted_date
2007-01-03          38.700001      234.029022      22.123693   12405100.0    15397500.0   76935100.0
2007-01-04          38.900002      241.871872      22.086641    6318400.0    15759400.0   45774500.0
2007-01-05          38.369999      243.838837      21.960684    6619700.0    13730400.0   44607200.0
2007-01-08          37.500000      242.032028      22.175547    6783000.0     9499200.0   50220200.0
2007-01-09          37.779999      242.992996      22.197784    5703000.0    10752000.0   44636600.0
...                       ...             ...            ...          ...           ...          ...
2020-06-09        2600.860107     1452.079956     189.800003    5176000.0     1681200.0   29783900.0
2020-06-10        2647.449951     1464.699951     196.839996    4946000.0     1588100.0   43872300.0
2020-06-11        2557.959961     1401.900024     186.270004    5800100.0     2357200.0   52854700.0
2020-06-12        2545.020020     1412.920044     187.740005    5429600.0     1832900.0   43345700.0
2020-06-15        2572.679932     1420.739990     188.940002    3865100.0     1523400.0   32712500.0
```